# Ambiguity issue with Vb.Net and MySql Connector

Tags: vb.net, datetime, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector, vbc

I'm running into a weird issue with a VB.Net project using the [MySql ADO.Net connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html). I have the following code:

```
Dim param As New MySqlParameter("@val29", MySqlDbType.DateTime)
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
Ambiguous invocation:
  Public Enum member Datetime As MySqlDbType (in Enum MySqlDbType)
  Public Enum member DateTime As MySqlDbType (in Enum MySqlDbType)
match
```

The difference between them, if you notice, is that `DateTime` is in a different case then `Datetime`. Since this is VB.Net and VB is case-insensitive, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Interestingly enough, I opened Object Browser in Visual Studio 2013 and, as you can see from the image below, there does seem to be two definitions of `DateTime`:

[image: Screen Shot]
.

Thinking maybe there was an issue with the DLL, I went to their website and downloaded the source code and rolled my own DLL. Same issue. I couldn't seem to find anything on the Internet about it, except for [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2909), which describes my issue exactly, except it seems to be due to a specific bug in Visual Studio 2015. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. That almost makes me think a Windows Update came along that changed the way the VB.Net compiler works. That doesn't make any sense though because updates are specific to Windows, not Visual Studio. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The one with the lowercase 'time' is marked with the ObsoleteAttribute in the Connector/Net 6.9.6 version you referenced when viewed in Reflector.  Now why you are getting an error, I have no idea as I did not in a quick test.  As a workaround until you get a real solution, try defining your defining your own instance of the Enum and using that in your parameter instantiation.  i.e. ``Dim sqlDTType As MySqlDbType = CType(12, MySqlDbType`` then  ``Dim param As New MySqlParameter("@val29", sqlDTType)``

Comment: After thinking over my above suggestion, this may be a better way to do instead of hardcoding the value (12). ``Dim sqlDTType As MySqlDbType = CType(GetType(MySqlDbType).GetField("DateTime", Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(Nothing), MySqlDbType)`` as there is no guaranty that the value will not change.  This way its tied to the spelling and character casing.

Comment: @TnTinMn - I like your suggestions. Its definitely hacky, but it'll get me past compilation so I can publish this program. Hoping for a real answer though so I can de-hackify my code.